# Probability of alternating shirts

Tags: probability, combinatorics

5 men are wearing red shirts and 5 men are wearing blue shirts. If the 10 men are lined up randomly, what is the probability that the colors will alternate?

My attempt: I started out by assuming that the first person was blue, and analyzing each sequential person case by case, I got $$\underbrace{\frac{5}{10}}_\text{blue}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{5}{9}}_\text{red}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{4}{8}}_\text{blue}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{4}{7}}_\text{red}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{3}{6}}_\text{blue}\dots,$$ and multiplying that by 2 (since the probability given the the first person chosen was wearing a red shirt should be the same), I got an answer of $$2\bigg(\frac{(5!)^2}{10!}\bigg)=\frac{1}{126}.$$ Is this right? And if it is, is there an easier way of going about this?

Comment: The result is correct.  An easier way: The total number of configurations is determined by picking, say, the spots for the five blue men, hence $\binom {10}{5}=252$.  There are exactly $2$ alternating patterns and $$\frac {2}{252}=\frac 1{126}$$

Comment: If you are at a home match at Barcelona, very high. This season, it is horizontal stripes.